# UX documentation

Tags: wireframe, documentation

How do you refer to "the user" in your wireframe notes and specs? Do you write it as: "I start typing", or "the user starts typing"? What format do you use? Also, does anybody have any examples from tech companies, like Google, Amazon, Apple... Curious what format they use.

Comment: Usually refer to the user in 3rd person "The User". Looking into other companies´protocols "the user" seems to be the norm. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7126596?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

When talking about **user stories** I use an "as a user, I want to..." format to really get inside of the user's way of thinking.

When talking about **user scenarios** I use a third person format like "Gary is 34 years old. As a user, he wants to..."

**General format**

I always start with creating personas based on user research I did to really get to know your users. A persona contains a name, age, sex, occupation, hobbies and dreams or vision.

After that I make a list of user stories based on user research and client/application goals for the application. This is also a nice way to check at the end of your progress if you have everything you set out for at the beginning of your progress.

When you have a persona and a list of user stories, I create a user scenario. This is like telling a story about your persona and how he or she completes a user story. ***Be specific. Think about where the persona is, not just what's on the screen. UX is about a lot more than just what's on your screen.***

There are a lot of great articles about user stories and scenarios. Here are a few I found online.

[How to Tell the User’s Story](https://www.newfangled.com/how-to-tell-the-users-story/)

[A step by step guide to scenario mapping](http://www.uxforthemasses.com/scenario-mapping/)

[How to Perfect Your UX with Persona Scenarios](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/04/how-to-perfect-your-ux-with-persona-scenarios/)

Comment: What about in your wireframe notes? What format do you use?

Comment: @janehouse In wireframe notes I use 'the user...' as format.